# c++ vector.push_back slower than python list.append

Tags: python, c++

c++    vector  push_back   one hundred million element, take 20 seconds.
c++    list    push_back   one hundred million element, will crash.
python list    append      one hundred million element, take 9 seconds.

python code example.

```py
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':

    start = time.time()
    s = []
    for i in xrange(100000000):         # one hundred million
        s.append(1)
    stop = time.time()
    print(stop - start)                 # second
```

c++ code example.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
using std::vector;
using std::find;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::chrono::steady_clock;
using std::chrono::duration_cast;
using std::chrono::nanoseconds;


int main(void) {
    auto start = steady_clock::now();
    auto max_size = 100000000;     // one hundred million
    vector<int> b(max_size);

    for (int i = 0; i < max_size; ++i) {
        b.push_back(1);                             
    }

    auto end = steady_clock::now();
    auto nano = duration_cast<nanoseconds>(end - start);

    cout << "elapsed(nano seconds): " << nano.count();
         << "; vector.size: " << b.size() << endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

i don't know why c++ vector/list is slower than python list.

thank all of you, i change `vector<int> b(max_size)` to `vector<int> b; b.reserve(max_size);` and enable optimization to /O2, it seems to be very faster, just take 100 ms.

Comment: You need to benchmark C++ with optimisations enabled.

Comment: You also want to pay attention to your own program messages. Your vector has twice as many elements as you think.

Comment: `vector<int> b(max_size);  `  your vector already has one hundred millon elements and then you are pushing one hundred millon to that vector.

Comment: it's worse than that. Do you understand what `vector<int> b(max_size);` actually *does* ? Not only does it allocate a hundred-million `int` values, it also value initializes them to zero. Replace `vector<int> b(max_size);` with `vector<int> b; b.reserve(max_size);`

Comment: Other commenters have raised some serious issues. My question is, why are you using `xrange()` in this, the year 2019 of our lord?

Comment: thank all of you, i change `vector<int> b(max_size)` to `vector<int> b; b.reserve(max_size);` and enable optimization to /O2, it seems to be very faster, just take 100 ms.

Comment: @WhozCraig I’m not OP, but as an expert in not understanding C++ I believe that I have the knowledge to make a highly accurate guess: Probably not ;)

Comment: Jokes aside though, OP, I think that fully understanding the differences between the two would take a good amount of digging into the functioning of each language.

Comment: Since you are filling the vector with the same value you can just do `vector<int> b(max_size, 1)` or use `std::fill` on a vector of a given size. That will be faster than doing lots of individual `push_back` operations.

Comment: @jignatius it probably will, but I think the point is that OP wanted to compare _append_ speed.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Wouldn't it be fair to use the best available tool in each language for a comparison of performance?

Comment: In general, I believe if Python outperforms C++ then something went wrong. The Python interpreter (I know and use) is written in C. So, nothing hinders you to resemble the exact code in C++ which is used in Python under the hood. As Python has the extra effort of interpreting its source code (or byte code), C++ should win always.

Comment: "*c++ list push_back one hundred million element, will crash*" - only if you run out of available memory.

Comment: @Scheff Of course, but not to compare _appending_. If instead we were comparing, say, how quickly each language can create a vector containing all the numbers from 1 to n, then yes, there would be far better alternatives to appending.